# Any other form do not work if use this ajax script

Tags: ajaxform

It is working fine for my enternal massageing sytem. but if I add any other form in same page that do not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var id_from = document.getElementById("idfrom").value;
    var msg_from = document.getElementById("msgfrom").value;
    var id_to = document.getElementById("idto").value;
    var msg_to = document.getElementById("msgto").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    
    var dataString= 'id_from=' + id_from + '&msg_from=' + msg_from + '&id_to=' + id_to + '&msg_to=' + msg_to + '&message=' + message;
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "includes/chat.inc.php",
        data: dataString,
         async: true,
        success: function(html){
            $('input[type="text"]').val('');
        
        
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'includes/loadmsg.inc.php',
            data:dataString,
              async: true,
            success:function(html){
                $('#chats').html(html);
            }
        }); 
        }
    })
})
```

})

I have tried use id insted of $("form"), then this script not work but added form work fine. is ther any way to change this code but work same as this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form")
```

should be assigned to specific div id or classname of that form.

```
$("#form1")
```

Comment: I have tried like $("#chat") and in form id='chat' but it do not work.

Comment: please also share your html. it will be better if you can setup codepen.